# What does ${"GLOBALS"} means in PHP?

Tags: php, variables

I've seen something like

```
${"globals"} = "whatever";
```

In a php file and i don't know what it does, it looks like some type of variable definition but i don't know what does it mean. some lights?

Comment: It's a crazy name for a variable, like `${0} = "wow";`

Comment: making sure the script doesn't access global scope variables through $GLOBALS array I guess.

Comment: Or simply RTM http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a weird way to declare a variable, do not confuse with [$GLOBALS](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php).

```
<?php
   ${0} = "wow";
   ${"globals"} = "whatever";
   echo ${0} . ' ## '. ${"globals"};

   echo "<pre>";
   print_r(get_defined_vars());
```

the print_r() will print something like this:

```
[0] => wow
[globals] => whatever
```